# only one value is equal to and selected in multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the exact same question as this:
[jQuery Hide / Show input when selected option is equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450695/jquery-hide-show-input-when-selected-option-is-equal-to)

However, it doesn't work when you go to multiple select, when the specific option is selected it works, but when you select another option alongside it stops working.

The question again is this: I want to show a div(#showme) if option 4 was selected, and I want to to work even if option 3 & 4 were selected, so at any given time if option 4 was selected the div should show.

This is the Javascript & HTML I have so far: (please note that I have more than one select in this form)

```js
$('select[multiple]').each(function() {
 $(this).change(function() {
  obj = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_desc';
  if($(this).val() == "4") {
   $(obj).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('hide');
   $(obj).css('display','block');
  }
  else {
   $(obj).parent().parent().parent().addClass('hide');
   $(obj).css('display','none');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="feedback_q1">Hello?</label>
   <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" name="feedback_q1[]" id="feedback_q1" multiple="multiple" title="Choose...">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row hide">
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="feedback_q1_desc">desc <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></label>
  <textarea name="feedback_q1_desc" id="feedback_q1_desc" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="desc" rows="2"></textarea>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gmp1675r/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiple selections are made, $(this).val() will contain an array of the values.  Iterate through them and check for '4'.  If $(this).val() is null, then nothing has been selected.

The example below does exactly what you want, including the changes after our extensive exchange in the comments and chat, including your most recent request to handle values pre-selected when the document loads.

Additionally, you were missing the bootstrap JavaScript file, and the files you were already including were in the wrong order and wrong location.  The example below includes all of the .js and .css files in the correct order and location.

**HTML**

```
<!-- These should be in head -->
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Body content -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="feedback_q1">Hello?</label>
            <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" name="feedback_q1[]" id="feedback_q1" multiple="multiple" title="Choose...">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4" selected>4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row hide">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="feedback_q1_desc">desc <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>

            </label>
            <textarea name="feedback_q1_desc" id="feedback_q1_desc" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="אנא פרט" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- These should be at the end of <body> -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Check a select for a specific value and show/hide div based on selection
// Select will come in as a jQuery object
function checkSelect(control) {

    // Build selector for associated description field
    var selector = '#' + control.attr('id') + '_desc';

    // Handle scenario where nothing is selected
    if (control.val() == null) {
        $(selector).parent().parent().parent().addClass('hide');
        $(selector).css('display', 'none');
        return;
    }

    // Get array containing selected values
    var vals = control.val();

    // Handle scenario where something is selected
    for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        if (control.val()[i] == "4") {
            $(selector).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('hide');
            $(selector).css('display', 'block');
            return; // Stop checking as we know the value we want is selected
        } else {
            $(selector).parent().parent().parent().addClass('hide');
            $(selector).css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
}

// This runs when the DOM is ready
$(function () {

    // Bind selectpicker
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

    // Iterate through all multiple selects
    $('select[multiple]').each(function () {

        // Check for pre-selected values when page first loads
        checkSelect($(this));

        // Bind to change event so that values are checked after something is changed
        $(this).change(function () {
            checkSelect($(this));
        });
    });
});
```

**Demo** (third version):  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/7ckp7epf/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73775/discussion-on-answer-by-benjamin-ray-only-one-value-is-equal-to-and-selected-in).

Comment: Thanks bluefeet, I wanted to go to chat before but I didn't have enough reputation points :P
Anyways, Benjamin Ray's solution works perfect, thanks B.R I really appreciate your help, you are amazing!

Comment: I have another question: This code will work only of the select is changed, how can I make it work also when the page is loaded and the field is already populated with the selected value "4"? I tried using .ready() but I keep getting errors :/

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the handling of pre-selected values. The code that inspects the selected values has been moved to its own function, which is now called on document.ready as well as when the selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">                                    
                                <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" name="Status" id="Status" multiple="multiple" title="Choose...">
                                    @foreach (SelectListItem item in ViewBag.Status)
                                    {
                                        if (item.Selected == false)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.Value" selected>@item.Text</option>
                                        }
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thank you for your contribution. Code only dumps are discouraged on SO. Consider an `edit` to highlight important bits, & explain how/why they solve the OP's issue. Quality answers receive more upvotes over time as future visitors learn something from your post that they can apply to their own code base. Additionally, please edit to use reasonable and consistent indentation in your posted code, for improved readability on this website across a variety of devices.